# What is the meaning of to be acted out?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "to be acted out" in the following sentences?

> As a result, it may abandon or modify some rites. But the myths that
>   have grown up around the rites may continue as part of the group’s
>   oral tradition and may even come **to be acted out** under conditions
>   divorced from these rites.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about [the dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/act%20out) as it relates to the exact cited context?

Comment: Please don't vote to reopen your on-hold questions without making any effort to improve them first. As the on-hold message says: *If this question can be reworded, **please edit the question**.* See [What does it mean when a question is put on hold?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To act (something) out.**

A transitive verb which means to perform something, as a script or rite.

The passive infinitive of this transitive verb is **to be acted out**.

They might *get performed* in contexts remote from (i.e. having no relation to, or no apparent relation to) their original ones.